# How large can a human or animal get?

Tags: fauna

Many legends and fables contain giant humans and animals that terrorize the people. Usually these beast are about 10-21 feet or 3.048-6.4008 meters. But in some pieces of literature, these humans and animals are much larger.

So my question is **how large can a single human or animal get and if so, what properties would change in order for them to be able to live at that size?**

More info : Sorry everyone. Is it off if you just do humans rounded to the nearest tenth? The environment of the human would most likely be in the forest which would be situated next to a desert at the equator. The seasonal pattern would be rain from February to December, and extreme heat in only January. The gravity of the planet would be approximately 1.12% stronger than Earth's gravity.

Comment: Please pick one: is it human or animal, and if animal which animal? Side note: what's the added value of specifying the size down to the tenth of mm?

Comment: Depends on how much the creature needs to support itself. In water they can be larger, case in point whales, in air I think sauropods are probably the largest you can get as far as earth examples go. You'll need to be more specific to your scenario if you want a proper answer.

Comment: What of the gravity of the planet? Earth-like? Lighter? Heavier? Relative percentages would do if you can't provide specific numbers.

Comment: Based on the added info, i *think* the OP is intending to ask "how large is a tribe of humans likely to get, at most, in these conditions", rather than discussions about square-cube law, material strength, etc... but some restatement of the question with detail of what is desired would be most helpful.

Comment: Are you sure you mean 1.12% more gravity ?  That's a trivial difference.  Did you mean 1.12 *times* larger (about 1/8th more) ?

Comment: The hu? have you left an incomplete sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Land animal sizes are pretty much governed by the square-cube law, by gravity, and caloric density.

Even with low gravity, even with a high oxygen fraction, as things get bigger their volume grows faster than their surface area and they have trouble shedding waste heat. For Earth, or a very Earth-like planet, you can basically look around you and see the biggest animals and use those for approximate maximums.

You can cheat this, but only a little. If you were to make some sort of cenitpedal "walking stick" insect, the shape of the creature itself mitigates some of the problems. Maybe you could make one half a mile long. Its shape allows for excess heat to be discarded, its mass can therefor be quite high, but with the animal no taller than an elephant gravity shouldn't make it outright impossible. Its weight could be evenly distributed across dozens or hundreds of sets of legs. Of course, its caloric needs are going to be significant to say the least (elephants are on the very edge of needing so much food that they could end up starving). It might be implausible that it could feed itself enough to stay alive. Nevermind that one wonders how it would circulate nutrients and waste removal. You start to run up against other constraints like the maximum speed of chemical diffusion in tissues, and hydraulics.